# Module Federation: ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed

Tags: webpack-module-federation

I have a MFE created which is working fine across multiple frontend . What I am looking into is when the remote URL is configured incorrectly how can we prevent host website not going down or crashing with the following error.

[image: Prevent this]

This is more like preventative MFE management . Where incase when getting remote URL from a registry or a service we want to be safe guarded of any errors on the host and prevent host from crashing..